# Unable to get the hidden field value on the same using link page in php

Tags: php

I have below code:

1.paging.php

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value= "banks-info" />
     <input class="button" type="submit"/>
  </form>
<a href="paging.php?page=2">next page</a>
```

Now I want to get the value of hidden value when I click "next page" link. How can I get it?

I tried below code:

```
if( isset($_GET['HDN_FormClicked']) && $_GET['HDN_FormClicked'] != "" ){
    echo $_GET['HDN_FormClicked'];
}
```

and this too

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['HDN_FormClicked']) && $_REQUEST['HDN_FormClicked'] != "" ){
        echo $_REQUEST['HDN_FormClicked'];
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use javascript for that

Comment: Hi Blueblazer172 I cant use javascript for my current page I have to use page postback.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hidden values using `$_GET` params like this:

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['HDN_FormClicked']) ? $_GET['HDN_FormClicked'] : '' ?>
```

So after implementing this to your code, it would be like this:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value= "<?php echo isset($_GET['HDN_FormClicked']) ? $_GET['HDN_FormClicked'] : '' ?>" />
    <input class="button" type="submit"/>
</form>
<a href="paging.php?page=2&HDN_FormClicked=banks-info">next page</a>
```

> Remember to append param in the url for the next page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Saumya Rastogi for your answer. The above solution is working but in the hidden field I am storing multiple values separated by commas and it may contains big string also. So I can't send it in the url is there any other solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use only Anchor tag, You can use it like

```
<a href="paging.php?page=2&HDN_FormClicked=banks-info">next page</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kevin Smk for your answer. The above solution is working but in the hidden field I am storing multiple values separated by commas and it may contains big string also. So I can't send it in the url is there any other solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then you can use  `<form method="post"  action="paging.php">` then submit your form and use post method to get `$_POST['HDN_FormClicked']` data.